# Like search from database tkinter treeview

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview

Hi good day to everyone I am a beginner of python programming and I have problem with searching database from my treeview. I dont know how to search "Like" method. although I can search my database but only one data and it must be accurate so It can be searched. Someone can help me with this please?

I just want to show data that has been like to others

here's my code

```
letter = tk.Label(t, text= "Search",  font=("Bahnschrift",15))
letter.configure(font = ('Cooper', 12, 'bold'),  fg = 'black')
letter.place(x=25, y=280)
s1 = tk.Entry(t, width=30, bd=3, bg = "sky blue", font = ("Bahnschrift", 10))
s1.place(x=100, y=280)
#SEARCH
    def searchs():
        if (s1.get()==""):
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please Complete the Provided Details!")
        else:
            for record in tree.get_children():
                tree.delete(record)
            databases = mysql.connector.connect(
            host ="localhost",
            user = "userdata",
            password = "",
            database = "facerecog"
            )
            conn = databases.cursor()
            conn.execute("SELECT * FROM record WHERE ids = %s ",(
            s1.get(),))
            i = 0
            for ro in conn:
                if ro[0]%2==0:
                    tree.insert('', i, text="",values=(ro[0], ro[1], ro[2], ro[3], ro [4], ro [5]), tags = ("even",))
                else:
                    tree.insert('', i, text="",values=(ro[0], ro[1], ro[2], ro[3], ro [4], ro [5]),tags = ("odd",))
                i = i + 1

    searchbutton = tk.Button(t, text = "Search", command = searchs)
    searchbutton.configure(font = ('Cooper', 13, 'bold'), bg = 'sky blue', fg = 'black')
    searchbutton.place(x=135, y=320)
```

And here my output of Search :[image: Searched Image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
databases = mysql.connector.connect(
            host ="localhost",
            user = "userdata",
            password = "",
            database = "facerecog"
            )
            conn = databases.cursor()
            conn.execute("SELECT * FROM record WHERE names LIKE %s ",( "%" +s1.get() +"%",))
```